# Access the same page from multiple urls (wildcard)

Tags: pages, urls

I want to serve a specific Wordpress page for multiple urls. Basically I want to point all the urls in a specific format to a known page:

```
/some-prefix-* => /target-page
```

And accessing `/some-prefix-and-here-something` it should load `/target-page`.

How to do this?

Note I do *not* want to redirect the user but to be able to serve an existing page to multiple urls.

The `.htaccess` looks like this:

```
# BEGIN s2Member GZIP exclusions
RewriteEngine On RewriteRule ^prefix-*$ some/path/to/directory-$1 [NC,L]
<IfModule rewrite_module>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|\?|&)s2member_file_download\=.+ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|\?|&)no-gzip\=1
    RewriteRule .* - [E=no-gzip:1]
</IfModule>
# END s2Member GZIP exclusions

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

I thought by adding `RewriteEngine On RewriteRule ^prefix-*$ some/path/to/directory-$1 [NC,L]` will serve `/prefix-*` from `some/path/to/directory-$1`. For example: when accessing `example.com/prefix-foo` should be the same with `example.com/some/path/to/directory-foo` (which resolves to `example.com/some/path/to/directory-foo/index.html`).

Also, if there is already a Wordpress page with the name `prefix-bar`, `/prefix-bar` should *not* load `example.com/some/path/to/directory-bar/index.html`.

Comment: Just do write redirect rules in your site .htaccess

Comment: Plugin recommendations are off topic, I have removed that part. I also believe this type of question was asked a while ago IIRC, so use the site search to look for possible solutions ;-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen True. I was just wondering if someone wrote this before. I also googled a little bit, but honestly I'm not a PHP hacker... :D I'm hoping that you guys will help me. I'm more in the [Node.js/JS side](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1420197/ionic%C4%83-biz%C4%83u).

Comment: @WPTC-Troop Something like `RewriteRule prefix-(.*) target-page`?

Comment: Yes  `RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^some-prefix-*$ http://example.com/target-page [R=301,L] `

Comment: The above is just an example for rewrite. It is easy, enjoy :)

Comment: @WPTC-Troop I don't want the redirect (probably just take out `[R=301,L]`?). Also, what happens with Wordpress pages having urls like `some-prefix-foo`? Is it possible not to override these?

Comment: Ok, then you can try like this `RewriteEngine On RewriteRule    ^some-prefix-*$    /target-page    [NC,L]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33508/discussion-between-wptc-troop-and-ionic-bizu).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`template_include`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include), but before you hook to this filter you must do the following steps:

1. Create page template. e.g: `page-target.php`

   ```
   <?php
   /**
    * Template Name: Page Target
    */
   ...
   ```
2. Manually query the contents of `target-page` on `page-target.php` template, because the global `$post` will be referencing to your `some-prefix-*` page.
3. (Optional): Edit and apply page template `Page Target` to your `/target-page` from the Page Attributes

Then add the following to your `functions.php` file

```
add_filter('template_include', function($template) {
    global $post;

    $prefix = 'some-prefix-'; // Your prefix
    $prefixExist = strpos($post->post_name, $prefix) !== false;

    if ($prefixExist) {
        return locate_template('page-target.php'); //Your template
    }

    return $template;
});
```

Above filter will override the template with `page-target.php` if condition met, otherwise default

#### Edit:

I think I have found a better way to resolve this using [`add_rewrite_rule`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule)

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
  $page_id = 123; //Your serve page id
  add_rewrite_rule('^some-prefix-.*', 'index.php?page_id=' . $page_id, 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

> **IMPORTANT:** Do not forget to flush and regenerate the rewrite rules database after modifying rules. From WordPress Administration Screens, Select Settings -> Permalinks and just click Save Changes without any changes.

Comment: Thanks! Will test this tomorrow. I think instead of `'index.php?page_id=' . $page_id` I can pass any existing path to an HTML file (which is stored in the public directory), right?

Comment: @IonicăBizău Yes you can, also don't forget to flush and regenerate the rewrite rules whenever you modify the above `add_rewrite_rule`

Comment: *don't forget to flush and regenerate the rewrite rules whenever you modify the above `add_rewrite_rule`* – good point. Hopefully it will work. If it does, I will consider adding a 50 point bounty to reward you! :-)

Comment: @IonicăBizău Sure, but please let me know if it doesn't work

Comment: I does work. I tested it out and working. Once this will go on production being tested enough, I will open a bounty to reward you. :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: @IonicăBizău Great, hope there won't be a problem on production as well

Comment: The update from January 2016 is a life-saver! :)

Answer (score 4):

**Note** that *search engines* might not like multiple paths to the same content!

Here I assume you want e.g.:

```
example.tld/some/path/to/painting-orange
example.tld/painting-blue
example.tld/painting-red
example.tld/painting-yellow
```

to behave like it was this page:

```
example.tld/paintings
```

but not so for paths like:

```
example.tld/painting-white/painting-brown/large
example.tld/painting-brown/small
```

The rule here is to match the prefix on the left side of `basename( $path )`.

Here's a little hack with the `request` filter, to check if the current page name is correctly prefixed:

```
<?php
/** 
 * Plugin Name: Wildcard Pages
 */
add_filter( 'request', function( $qv )
{
    // Edit to your needs
    $prefix = 'painting-';
    $target = 'paintings';

    // Check if the current page name is prefixed
    if(    isset( $qv['pagename'] )
        && $prefix === substr( basename( $qv['pagename'] ), 0, strlen( $prefix ) ) 
    )
        $qv['pagename'] = $target;

    return $qv;
} );
```

Modify this to your needs. Then create the plugin file `/wp-content/plugins/wpse-wildcard-pages/wpse-wildcard-pages.php` file and activate the plugin from the backend.

We could also add a check with [`get_page_by_path()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_path) on the target page, just to make sure it exists. We might also want to restrict this to certain post types.

Comment: Where should we put this code?

Comment: We put that in `functions.php` and we got a blank page everywhere. Also, how can I serve a static index.html file located at `/foo/bar/index.html` (where `bar` is dynamic) instead of a Wordpress page?

Comment: Sorry for the syntax error, was one extra ). I updated the answer regarding that. Here I assumed the target page was a WordPress page that you could adjust it's content to your needs. It's possible to include static html file like this [hack](http://pastie.org/private/ugsiqbqwzyblardne11jq) (without css/js), but if you're dealing with serving such (external) static HTML files, then I would recommend you to try to solve this purely with the webserver instead. @IonicăBizău

Comment: *But if you're dealing with serving external static HTML files, then I would recommend you to try to solve this purely with the webserver instead.* – we have already paths like `/foo/bar/some-page/index.html`. This allows us to access in the browser `/foo/bar/prefix-some-page`. Instead of this, I want to access `/prefix-some-page` which will serve ``/foo/bar/prefix-some-page`. The `prefix-some-page` is something that is dynamic, so I want to do something like: `/prefix-* => /foo/bar/prefix-$1/index.html`. This will happen only if there is no `prefix-...` page in the Wordpress. How to do this?

Comment: You could try: `RewriteRule ^(.*)prefix-([^/]+)/?$ /foo/bar/prefix-$2/index.html [NC,L]` to serve e.g. `http://example.tld/prefix-test/` as it were  `http://example.tld/foo/bar/prefix-test/index.html` But this is of course unaware if there's any such page already in WordPress. To add such a check, maybe this rule would need to be generated within WordPress on a reqular basis?  @IonicăBizău

Answer (score 0):

Create a hook to init and wp_redirect when the current post's slug starts with your prefix.

```
function wp_init() {

    global $post;
    $slug = $post->post_name;
    $prefix = 'foobar';
    if (substr($slug, 0 strlen($prefix))==$prefix) {
        wp_redirect(123); // your page id
    }

}
add_action('init', 'wp_init');
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want redirect, I want to serve the page.

Comment: @IonicăBizău you can redirect to any page as well as to a page with the message "this page has been reserved".

Comment: @IonicăBizău You mean `/some-prefix-and-here-something` would serve `/target-page` without change in url?

Comment: @rahilwazir Exactly!

Comment: @rahilwazir I added the `.htaccess` file. How can I edit it to get this working, but without redirect?

Comment: @IonicăBizău You can't using `.htaccess` because `.htaccess` serve actual files internally not application pages. Either do a redirection or use [`template_include`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include) filter hook to modify the template

Comment: Can you add an example?

Comment: @IonicăBizău See [my answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/213322/36349)