# How to show the root webpage on all subpaths

Tags: pages, url-rewriting, urls, routing

I want to show the same page on all the subpaths on my web site

```
/events/
/events/firstOne
/events/secondOne/edit
/events/whatever/blahblahbla/helloworld
```

All that urls must load the same root page.

On that page (`/events/`) I have a `react` script that will handle everything from there with `react router`, but, right now, if I try to load any thing different than `/events/`, I just get a not found error.

How can I match a wildcard on that url?

EDIT:

I have tried to do it with `add rewrite rule`, as recomended on this answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/213322/164509, but doesn't work either

I have added this to my `funtions.php` file:

```
// /public_html/wp-content/themes/kava/functions.php
<?php


function custom_rewrite_basic() {
  add_rewrite_rule('^events/([a-z]+)/', 'show_event', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');



if ( ! class_exists( 'Kava_Theme_Setup' ) ) {

    /**
     * Sets up theme defaults and registers support for various WordPress features.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */ 
    class Kava_Theme_Setup {

        ....
```

Then I refresh the rewrite rules database by clicking on save permalinks on the admin page.

But when I try to load `/events/asdf` I still get a 404 not found error.

Comment: And what exactly is that "/events/" page? Is it a page? Is it a custom post type archive? Is it a taxonomy? And how does the React app know, where should it work? Is the 'events' part hardcoded?

Comment: It is a `page` wich only contains the header, footer and the `<script>` tag