# Create one page, land any other URLs starting with that page to the same place

Tags: url-rewriting

I would like to create a Wordpress page, for example "Foods"

Then I want every single one of the following URLs to land on the "Foods" page. There could be unlimited number of URLs that lead to the "Foods" page:

https://website.com/food/burger

https://website.com/food/pizza

https://website.com/food/stew

https://website.com/food/lasagne

https://website.com/food/etc1

https://website.com/food/etc2

https://website.com/food/etc3

https://website.com/food/and_so_on

How could I achieve this? Many thanks in advance.

Regards

Comment: Look up server redirects. Also, there are a ton of WordPress plug-ins that'll do what you want (e.g. https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/).

Comment: @maryisdead I don't want to redirect, I just want to serve the page as it comes. The data inside the page will be dynamic. But I also don't want to create n number of actual pages in Wordpress either.

Comment: Ah, my bad. Misread your request then. Take a look at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/213016/access-the-same-page-from-multiple-urls-wildcard

Comment: Thanks @maryisdead, that was exactly what I needed.